# Angular2 injected component html template not resetting

Tags: angular, components, inject

When a user clicks on a button, a modal pops up with a component injected into the modal. For each component injection, is a new instance of the component injected? If so, does anyone know why the modified HTML of the injected component is not reset if I click on the button again and another instance of the component pops into the modal?

**Modal**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'customize-modal-component',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html'
})

export class CustomizeModalComponent {
    private injectedComponet;

    showChildModal() {
        this.childModal.show();
    }

    injectComponent(component) {
        let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        this.injectedComponent = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    }

    hideChildModal() {
        if(this.injectedComponent) this.injectedComponent.destroy();
        this.childModal.hide();
    }
}
```

**Injected Component Into Modal**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'injected-component',
  template: '<div *ngIf="!validated">Successfully Validated {{validationId}}</div>'
})

export class InjectedComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private validationId;
    private validated = false;

    modifyVariables(){
        validated = true
        validationId = 'ABYLO123';
    }
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
import { ComponentToBeInjected } from '../../component-injected.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent-component.html'
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    activateModal(){
        this.modal.injectComponent(ComponentToBeInjected);
        this.modal.showChildModal();
    }

}
```